# Norm bound of an $L^2$ convolution function

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{D},\nu)$ are two measure space, where $X$ is a compact metric space and $\mathscr{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$- algebra on $X$. Let $\alpha:X\rightarrow Y$ be a measure preserving map(special map). Let $\mu=\int\mu_y\,d\nu(y)$ be the disintegration as described in [Theorem 5.8](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q1PGVOCQeDUfY_fb-ur3x2aM5jblENI5). Define the measure $\mu\,\times_{Y}\,\mu$ on the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X\,\times\,X$ by $\mu\,\times_{Y}\,\mu(A):=\int_{y}(\mu_y\,\times\,\mu_y)(A)\,d\nu(y)$. If $H\in L^2(X\,\times\,X,\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{B},\mu\,\times_Y\,\mu)$ and $\phi\in L^2(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$, the convolution $H*\phi$ is defined by $(H*\phi)(x)=\int H(x,x')\phi (x')\,d\mu_{\alpha(x)}(x')$.

**Problem:** Prove that $\left\lVert H*\phi\right\lVert_y\leq \left\lVert H\right\lVert_y\left\lVert\phi\right\lVert_y$, where $\left\lVert H*\phi\right\lVert_y$ is the $L^2$ norm w.r.t the measure $\mu_y$, and similarly others.

I got stuck in this while studying Compact extension from 'Recurrence in Ergodic Theory and Combinatorial Number Theory' by Harry Furstenberg. For the details discussion, see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DsoFtRvpViS3dsusT_YlYetyK-xRl2L/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you seen the proof of a fact like : The convolution is a Banach norm on $L^1(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$? It resembles the statement you want to prove.

Comment: @surajit is my answer below helpful? In particular, do you know if $\mu_y$ is supported on $\phi^{-1}(\{y\})$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, $\mu_{y}$ is supported on $\phi^{-1}(\{y\})$ when $\alpha$ is a special map. Thanks a lot for your help. Please allow me some time to see your proof, and I'll accept it with the bounty.

Comment: @Surajit oh, that's great! take your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is a special map, $\mu_y$ is supported on $\alpha^{-1}(\{y\})$. Therefore,$$||H*\phi||_y^2 = \int_X |H*y|^2(x_0)d\mu_y(x_0) = \int_X \left| \int_X H(x_0,x)\phi(x)d\mu_{\alpha(x_0)}(x)\right|^2 d\mu_y(x_0)$$ $$ = \int_X \left|\int_X H(x_0,x)\phi(x)d\mu_y(x)\right|^2d\mu_y(x_0)$$ $$\le \int_X \left[\int_X |H(x_0,x)|^2d\mu_y(x)\right]\cdot\left[\int_X |\phi(x')|^2 d\mu_y(x')\right]d\mu_y(x_0)$$ $$ = \int_X \left[\int_X \int_X |H(x_0,x)|^2d\mu_y(x)d\mu_y(x_0)\right]|\phi(x')|^2d\mu_y(x')$$ $$ = ||H||_y^2 ||\phi||_y^2.$$